# How to get apk expansion files after installed application?

Tags: android, livecode

I use livecode for developed. My project larger than 50MB. It's can't publish to google play store. So I build standalone application without resource files. And I create obb file with jobb.

Step by Step

1. My project package name is com.tester.guru Version name is 3.0 and Version code is 3
2. I set signing to "Sign for development only" (for simple install application to my device.)
3. I set install location to "Allow External Storage"
4. I create obb file with jobb. Command below:

   jobb -d resources directory  -o main.3.com.tester.guru.obb -k guruasean -pn com.tester.guru -pv 3
5. Now I have 2 files:APK file and main.3.com.tester.guru.obb file
6. Copy the installation file (.apk) to the SD Card and Install it.
7. Copy the obb file to /Android/obb/

After I do 7 steps and run application. It not show image because image wrong path.

How do I do for solve this problem.

Comment: What is the path to the image? What have you tried to access the obb file so far? You might try to access the obb file the same way as a zip file, but I haven't tested this. It may fail, because the obb file may be encrypted.

Comment: My image path is "./temp/assets/images/splash.png". Could you please specify how to testing access obb file in step by step because I'm not sure how to test this. Thanks in advice.

Comment: When you put the image into an obb file, that file path no longer exists. In Java for Android, you need to use a special API and specify the path within the obb file. I'll do a test when I find time for it.

Comment: Instead of using jobb, just put the code in your app to create a directory in /mnt/sdcard/ and the download all necessary files from internet.

Comment: @MaxV Cloud you please explain more for this in step by step, or give me an example for this solution?